# Installing superscalar benchmark

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, benchmarking

I have follow the steps of installing `sperscalar` benchmark  , and every thing is seems to be okay , but when i used the command  `make config-alpha` , i have the following problem  :

```
    make "MAKE=make" "CC=gcc" "AR=ar qcv" "AROPT=" "RANLIB=ranlib" "CFLAGS=`./sysprobe -flags` -DDEBUG -O -g -Wall" "OEXT=o" "LEXT=a" "EEXT=" "X=/" "RM=rm -f" libcheetah.a
/bin/sh: 1: ./sysprobe: not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/matsbror/simplescalar/simplesim-3.0/libcheetah'
make[1]: `libcheetah.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/matsbror/simplescalar/simplesim-3.0/libcheetah'
my work is done here...
```

So , what is that ?

Comment: Your makefile needs an executable call `sysprob`, but it does not find it.

Comment: @jml , but it's exist in the same directory that makefile set in !

Comment: Try to see if it is executable and in the good directory (you can add some `pwd` before the call to `./sysprobe` in the makefile).